# Query where not in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an `Image` model and a `User` model.
I join them together with a HABTM relationship called `likes`.
Also an `Image` belongs to an `User`

I am trying to find all images that dont belong to an user and havent been liked by that user.
I can't quite seem to come up with the where conditions.

This is what I have:

```
@image = Image.where("user_id != :user_id AND image_id NOT IN :likes", {:user_id => session[:user].id, :likes => session[:user].likes}).first
```

Here are my `Image` and `User` models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
# attr_accessible :title, :body
 belongs_to :user
 has_and_belongs_to_many :likes, :class_name => 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # attr_accessible :title, :body
 has_many :submitted_images, :class_name => 'Image'
 has_and_belongs_to_many :likes, :class_name => 'Image'
end
```

Can someone help my come up with this query? Thanks!

**Edit**

The Syntax error I am getting:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "3"
LINE 1: ... FROM "images"  WHERE (user_id != 1 AND image_id NOT IN 3,5) LIMIT...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "images".* FROM "images"  WHERE (user_id != 1 AND image_id NOT IN 3,5) LIMIT 1
```

If you look at my `images_users` AKA `likes` table you can see where the `3,5` is coming from in my error:

[image: My Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should use some meaningful name your associations. For example you could use `has_and_belongs_to_many :appreciators, :class_name => 'User'` or something similar, that makes more sense. Though your query is not gonna be affected by this. :)

Anyways, What I can suggest for your current setup is:

```
@image = Image.where("user_id != :user_id AND id NOT IN (:likes)", {:user_id => session[:user].id, :likes => session[:user].likes}).first
```

Comment: hmm I'm still getting the same error - Just updated the question with it.

Comment: You're welcome. :) The reason was we were not specifying the braces around the likes(array). So SQL was not able to understand what it should look into. :)